# My Belkin F7D4301 Router has slow wireless speeds but fast Ethernet speeds

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, ethernet

My Belkin F7D4301 Router has the fastest wireless speed of maybe 2MBps but wired with a cat5e cable to my asus laptop of almost 7MBps. I have a one smart tv, one blu ray, one roku, and a nexus 7 using the 2.4 channel.

My Wireless 2.4 settings are channel 11, Extension channel 7, Wireless mode N (have tried with just g and b, g, and n modes), Bandwidth 20/40, Protected mode on, QOS off.

I've talked to Belkin tech support, they are the ones who had me set up my 2.4 channel this way but my wireless speeds stay just under 2MBps, they just want to keep sending me the same model Router because they think each of the new ones they send me is defective.

Am I doing something wrong or is 2MBps the best wireless speed I'm going to get?

Comment: What's the wireless card in the ASUS?

Comment: Which device are you using to measure the wireless speed, and what is the other endpoint for the performance test? Also, just to make the question more clear, would you mind restating your question in megabits per second? Networking and communications speeds are always done in 1,000,000's of bits per second (in contrast to disk & file I/O speeds which are done in 1,048,576's of Bytes per second).

Answer (score -1):

All your devices have to be "N"-rated to get the higher speeds.  You have to put all those devices in "N" only mode.  If just one of those devices that you mentioned sharing your wireless channel is only "g" or less rated then all your devices will be throttled at that speed, because your AP will have to throttle down for backwards compatability.  The best you can get with a 'g' rated wireless AP is 54mbps.  Now you will never get 54mbps with 'g' in real life.  Because of the overhead and other factors with wireless technology you'll get about 36mbps (if you're lucky) or 24mbps (pretty standard).

So if you have high speed internet, like fios or cable, that is rated at something like 50mbps you'll be lucky to see 11-20 mbps from your wireless machine.  When you "plug in" over cable you don't have the overhead of wireless and you are able to pump those high speeds.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Please don't perpetuate the false myth that Wi-Fi networks only go as fast as the slowest client's technology. It has never been true. When an N client is transmitting or receiving on a b/g/n network, it transmits (or receives) at N rates (assuming it's within range where N rates are better than G or B rates) regardless of whether there are G or B devices on the network. Also, your estimated max and typical actual throughputs for G networks are way too high.

Comment: hmm after looking at what I wrote I can see where you think I'm perpetuating a myth. I was really trying to explain why he's seeing what he's seeing.  IF you have an AP that is running b/g/n you're not going to see full N rates.  If you have b/g clients on the net you're going to have wait longer to transmit.  Also, there may be hidden node problems or power problems.  I was just trying to point him the right direction.